# python xlsxwriter absence of a chart

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I want to built a diagram with python xlsxwriter, but as result I have no chart in saved file.

Here is my code:

```
import xlsxwriter
from sys import stdin
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('res.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
data = []
for stroka in stdin:
    ######
    if stroka == '\n':
        break
    ######
    stroka = stroka.split()
    data.append((stroka[0], stroka[1]))
for row, (name, val) in enumerate(data):
    worksheet.write(row, 0, name)
    worksheet.write(row, 1, val)
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!B1:B' + str(row + 1)})
worksheet.insert_chart('C3', chart)
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program should work if there is data in the array. Here is a slightly modified version of you code with sample data:

```
import xlsxwriter


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('res.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

data = [('apple', 60), ('cherry', 30), ('pecan', 10)]

for row, (name, val) in enumerate(data):
    worksheet.write(row, 0, name)
    worksheet.write(row, 1, val)

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!B1:B' + str(row + 1)})

worksheet.insert_chart('A5', chart)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

However, you probably want to add a category as well like below. Note, this uses the alternative list syntax in `add_series()`:

```
import xlsxwriter


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('res.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

data = [('apple', 60), ('cherry', 30), ('pecan', 10)]

for row, (name, val) in enumerate(data):
    worksheet.write(row, 0, name)
    worksheet.write(row, 1, val)

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})
chart.add_series({'categories': ['Sheet1', 0, 0, row, 0],
                  'values':     ['Sheet1', 0, 1, row, 1]})

worksheet.insert_chart('A5', chart)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much